# Stuck at "minimal BASH-like line editing" when I turn on my computer

Tags: 16.04, grub2, boot-repair

When I turn on my computer it shows a screen with

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing...
```

My Ubuntu is 16.04. I tried reboot and running the Boot Repair Tool in a live session, but it didn't solve my problem.

Boot Repair gave me this [Boot Info script output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XcQDSqdPtw/)

Comment: Where is your Ubuntu installed to?  I don't see any ext3/ext4 partitions on your drive in that link.  Did you recently install Windows on the drive?  It looks like you have Windows installed, but GRUB is installed to the beginning of the drive but no Ubuntu installation or Linux for that matter that GRUB looks to for it to load libraries for it to boot.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed it, thank you. Actually, I have a HDD with Windows and a SSD with Ubuntu. So I guess the problem is about my SSD recognition, because I've opened here the "Disks", and my SSD is not showing up. But it was working, I've just turned off my computer, when I turned on this happend.

Comment: Check your cables to your SSD.  One of the biggest problems to SSD drives in my opinion is that there is no warning for when they go bad.  So you might want to try it in other systems as well if need be.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the problem was it, I disconnected and reconnected my ssd and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was that my ssd wasn't connected properly, and it wasn't being recognized, because I use a caddy adapter in place of my cd driver on my laptop. And probably it was caused by the transportation of my device